# Delivery costs are not being added to total

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I find that when i add some products too my basket the delivery costs are no being called in the totals block

[image]

But when i add more products and go back to the cart then the delivery charges have been added, i have turned on the template hints and I can see the template shipping.phtml isn't being called when i view the basket first but is being called once i go off the cart adn add another product.

The .phtml file that is calling the shipping.phtml is totals.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
    <div class="cart-msrp-totals"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <tfoot>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer'); ?>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i cant see anything which calls the shipping, So i am stuck as to where to look or what is going on, if someone could shed some light on my situation or know how to fix this problem could you let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Shipping costs will be collected when you've entered your shipping address, so in checkout process. There is an extension to display default shipping costs in cart before user has entered an address. Maybe this solves your problem.

https://github.com/integer-net/Autoshipping

Comment: If that's the case why does it add the shipping if i go into the basket, out of the basket, add another product then back into the basket again?